# Setting bounds for dynamic arrays

Tags: arrays, delphi, dynamic-arrays, delphi-xe7

Static arrays allow to define their low and high bounds:

```
StaticArray : array[5..7] of Integer;
```

I don't know how to do the same thing with dynamic arrays at runtime.

For example, if I need to copy the elements from a static array, keeping the same indexes, I don't know how to set its low bound to `Low(StaticArray)` and high bound to `High(StaticArray)`:

```
var
  StaticArray : array[5..7] of Integer;
  DynamicArray : array of Integer;
  i : integer;
begin
  //initializing static array
  StaticArray[5] := 1;
  StaticArray[6] := 2;
  StaticArray[7] := 3;

  //setting the same length and bounds to the dynamic array
  //?

  //copying elements
  i := 0;
  for i := Low(StaticArray) to High(StaticArray) do
    DynamicArray[i] := StaticArray[i];
end;
```

Is there any way for setting the low/high bounds of a dynamic array, or do they always have `0` as low bound and `Length(Array) - 1` as high bound?

Comment: Why do you want it? I understand that lower and upper bound is information on its own (i.e. have a scale of `1.. 6` instead of `0.. 5`), but that would be as trivially pointless as distinguishing between fixed point decimals and plain integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you have a question about the Delphi language, you should consult the official documentation. In this case, the section named [Dynamic Arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) on [Structured Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)) says the following:

> Dynamic arrays are always integer-indexed, always starting from 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way for setting the low/high bounds of a dynamic array

No.

> or do they always have `0` as low bound and `Length(Array) - 1` as high bound?

Yes.  Which means you can do this:

```pascal
var
  StaticArray : array[5..7] of Integer;
  DynamicArray : array of Integer;
  i : integer;
begin
  //initializing static array
  StaticArray[5] := 1;
  StaticArray[6] := 2;
  StaticArray[7] := 3;

  //setting the same length and bounds to the dynamic array
  SetLength(DynamicArray, Length(StaticArray));

  //copying elements
  for i := Low(StaticArray) to High(StaticArray) do
    DynamicArray[i-Low(StaticArray)] := StaticArray[i];
end;
```

Or, just use two separate index variables:

```pascal
var
  StaticArray : array[5..7] of Integer;
  DynamicArray : array of Integer;
  i, j : integer;
begin
  //initializing static array
  StaticArray[5] := 1;
  StaticArray[6] := 2;
  StaticArray[7] := 3;

  //setting the same length and bounds to the dynamic array
  SetLength(DynamicArray, Length(StaticArray));

  //copying elements
  j := 0;
  for i := Low(StaticArray) to High(StaticArray) do begin
    DynamicArray[j] := StaticArray[i];
    Inc(j);
  end;
end;
```

Or, since your arrays contain non-managed trivial types, just replace the whole loop with a single `Move()` call instead:

```pascal
var
  StaticArray : array[5..7] of Integer;
  DynamicArray : array of Integer;
begin
  //initializing static array
  StaticArray[5] := 1;
  StaticArray[6] := 2;
  StaticArray[7] := 3;

  //setting the same length and bounds to the dynamic array
  SetLength(DynamicArray, Length(StaticArray));

  //copying elements
  Move(StaticArray[Low(StaticArray)], DynamicArray[0], Length(DynamicArray) * SizeOf(Integer));
end;
```